# crystal report 8.5 how to know how long a report runs

Tags: crystal-reports

My new company got some legacy crystal report 8.5. Now I need to look into one of them because it runs too long. I run the rpt file using crystal report. I need to know how long it runs without keep an eye on it because it may run long time. Any idea? Thanks. I am fairly new to crystal report

BTW, it runs against a sql server 2005 database. I wouldn't use sql profiler until there is no other way to do it.

Comment: I would look on the db it queryies an check query run time.

Comment: It runs against a stored procedure and there are lot of queries inside. I know I can use sql profiler, but that would be my last resort.

Comment: how about logging the time at the beginning of the sproc then again at the end and log the length somewhere? (if you want to know how long the query takes and not how long the report takes to render etc)

Answer (score 0):

You're using CR 8.5 or these reports were written on 8.5?

I can't speak about extremely old versions of CR, but any reasonably recent version has this information by clicking on "Report" -> "Performance Information"

Comment: I am using CR 8.5. There is no Performance Information in "Report".

Comment: @thotwielder 8.5 is well over a decade old now... it maybe time for your company to spring for a new version, especially if you're actively maintaining/developing. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.